# Why chart is not shown on web?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, charts

I tried to create new chart and add this `Chart Chart1 = new Chart();` into my Cs file. Then I add the series and chartarea to create the chart dynamically, but strangely, when the code is executed, no chart is shown.

If I do not add that statement in and define Chart ID in Aspx file like this: `<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">` then try to create chart dynamically in Cs file, it works. But I want to create new chart every time and do not want to depend on defining Chart ID to produce chart dynamically.

This is my codes of when defining Chart ID in Aspx file to produce chart dynamically, chart can be produced (it works):

```
    //Aspx file:

<asp:scriptmanager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:scriptmanager>

        </div>
        <asp:updatepanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <contenttemplate>

 <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">

                </asp:Chart>

  <asp:placeholder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:placeholder>
        </contenttemplate>
        </asp:updatepanel>

//Cs file:
            Chart1.DataSource = tg;
            Chart1.Width = 600;
            Chart1.Height = 350;

            Chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
            Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
            List<object> lst = tg.AsEnumerable().ToList<object>();

            foreach (DataRow row in tg.Rows)
                Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row["Status"], new object[] { row["Min"], row["Max"], row["Avg"], row["Percentile25"], row["Percentile50"], row["Percentile75"] });

            if(tg.Rows.Count>0)
            {
                string title = (tg.Rows[2]["Process"].ToString());
            }

            //create chartareas
            ChartArea ca = new ChartArea();
            ca.Name = "ChartArea1";
            ca.AxisX = new Axis();
            ca.AxisY = new Axis();
            Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(ca);

            //databind
            Chart1.DataBind();
            Chart1.Visible = true;
```

This is my codes when I tried to create new chart by adding in this: `Chart Chart1 = new Chart()` in Cs file and didn't define ChartID in Aspx file (does not work):

```
    //Aspx file:
 </div>
        <asp:updatepanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <contenttemplate>

<asp:Chart runat="server">

                </asp:Chart>
                </br>

        <asp:placeholder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:placeholder>
        </contenttemplate>
        </asp:updatepanel>

//Cs file:
            Chart Chart1 = new Chart();
            Chart1.DataSource = tg;
            Chart1.Width = 600;
            Chart1.Height = 350;

            Chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
            Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
            List<object> lst = tg.AsEnumerable().ToList<object>();

            foreach (DataRow row in tg.Rows)
                Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row["Status"], new object[] { row["Min"], row["Max"], row["Avg"], row["Percentile25"], row["Percentile50"], row["Percentile75"] });

            if(tg.Rows.Count>0)
            {
                string title = (tg.Rows[2]["Process"].ToString());
            }

            //create chartareas
            ChartArea ca = new ChartArea();
            ca.Name = "ChartArea1";
            ca.AxisX = new Axis();
            ca.AxisY = new Axis();
            Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(ca);

            //databind
            Chart1.DataBind();
            Chart1.Visible = true;
```

How to add in this statement: `Chart Chart1 = new Chart();` into Cs file to create new chart every time during execution instead of depending on defining Chart ID in Aspx file (`<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">`) to create the chart dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, Chart1 is not the same chart instance as the one defined in markup. That is why nothing is shown. Using the chart defined in markup is the same as defining a new one because it recreates on each request. You're trying to solve a problem you don't have.
Otherwise you would have to dynamically add Chart1 to the form's controls collection and that would be pointless.

Comment: hi @Crowcoder, I can create chart dynamically, but what if I have to loop through each gridview row and create more than one chart in one go, will this work? becos I thought one chart is supposed to have one chart id? that's why I want to dynamically add Chart1 to the form's controls collection.

Comment: You might be able to use a Repeater control, otherwise [add controls dynamically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1(v=vs.100).aspx)